# Issue in Liferay Iframe

Tags: iframe, liferay, alfresco, alfresco-share

I tried to display alfresco share in liferay Iframe.
Problem is If I bond Iframe with Alfresco Share page. Then Iframe is automatic continuously scrolling vertically. May be the folders are more in alfresco.
How can I stop this continuously scrolling from Iframe??

Thanks

Comment: Are you using Liferay's OTB "Iframe" portlet?

Comment: yes I am using OTB iframe portlet

Comment: Have you tried adding maximized height?

Comment: In Iframe Portlet In Look and feel option->Advaced styling I set this css overflow-x: hidden;
overflow-y: scroll;
height:100%;
width:100%;

Comment: No, in Iframe portlet > Configuration > Display Setting > uncheck " Resize Automatically" checkbox, there is option to add maximized & normal height.

Comment: In Height Normal text  box by default 600.and it doesn''t take 100%..How can I give height so that I can view all folders of my alfresco repo??

Comment: Can you share the link? There is bit confusion, if you want to show all the folders then why are you worrying about the height?

Comment: Right now I can't scroll vertically and can't view all folders.I have scrollbar horizontally but not vertically

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93331/discussion-between-parkash-kumar-and-user3855589).